# How to get the parameter sending by post method in php included file?

Tags: php, jquery

Good day. I am having the following code snippet in init.php.

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
include_once(__SITE_PATH . 'view/' . $_REQUEST['page'] . EXT);

$loginobj = new $_REQUEST['page']($_REQUEST['billingentitynuber']);
$text = $loginobj->$_REQUEST['content']();
echo $text;
?>
```

In Jquery I am having the function Jquery_event.js

```
$("#entertoapp").click(function()
{         
  alert($("#btval").val());
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "init.php?page=processing&content=enterintoapplication&btval=" + $("#btval").val(),

    success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
      if(msg==1)
        window.location.href='index.php?page=processing&content=mycontent';
    }
  });
});
```

In processing.php I am having

```
<?php
class processing
{
  public function enterintoapplication()
  {
    global $billingentityname;
    $_SESSION['btval'] = $billingentityname;
    echo $billingentityname;
  }
}
?>
```

My problem is I am getting all the parameters in the init.php. But when I call a function I need to get in the processing.php in the enterintoapplication function (i.e. I am expecting `btval` in the `enterintoapplication` function). How can I achieve this? I tried to get `$_REQUEST['btval']` within the function. But I didn't get.

Comment: Thanks Jordan.Thanks for the edit.I am also trying to do like this.But I got failure.How can I edit like this.I put four space also.

Comment: vinothkumar: You must also have a blank line between your text and the beginning and end of your code. You do not need to use ` for code blocks.

Comment: @jordan Thanks.I will try in the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning the values to variables, for example this works for PHP 4:

```
class processing
{
  function enterintoapplication()
  {
    echo "hello";
  }
}

$className="processing";
$functionName="enterintoapplication";

$loginobj=new $className();
$text=$loginobj->$functionName();
echo $text;
```

Paste it here to verify it works: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Pls,pay attention to "$functionName", here it keeps the "$".

Nevertheless, for security reasons, you should be attentive to what people can do if they change the value "page".

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem correctly, but with some general information, you should get out of this.

`$_REQUEST` is a superglobal, that means that variable will always be accessible from everywhere within your script. If your problem is you can't find the `btval` variable that was in your URL, you are doing something else wrong. If your url=`http://someUrl/test.php?btval=banana` you should always get `banana` if you evaluate `$_REQUEST['btval']`. `$_SESSION` is another superglobal to access the PHP session, and has nothing to do with URL variables.

My guess:
Try changing

```
$_SESSION['btval'] = $billingentityname;
```

into

```
$billingentityname = $_REQUEST['btval'];
```

In that case, your real mistake was that you've put the two variables in this assignment in the incorrect order. `$a = $b` means: put the contents of `$b` into `$a`.